# Dom manipulation rebuilds entire DOM structure

Tags: javascript, dom

From the below link in 2nd stanza I see the statement :"As an example, let's say that you have a list that contains ten items. You check off the first item. Most JavaScript frameworks would rebuild the entire list. That's ten times more work than necessary! Only one item changed, but the remaining nine get rebuilt exactly how they were before.  Rebuilding a list is no big deal to a web browser, but modern websites can use huge amounts of DOM manipulation. Inefficient updating has become a serious problem."          Can this be explained in detail please . How manipulating one dom element rebuilds the entire parent??

https://www.codecademy.com/articles/react-virtual-dom

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have a list of elements in a certain order, and that list is updated every second (for example the list of the last items sold in a store, ordered by popularity). Any item can be out of the list in every update and new items can enter at random positions. This makes hard to update the list by moving, replacing or inserting elements, so the easiest approach is to regenerate the list on any update.

This scenario is a worst case one, but in general this approach is the most common because is the easiest one: forget the old list and place a new one, even in there is no changes at all.

React, with its "virtual DOM", is capable of taking the new list, comparing it with the old one and detect the needed changes in the "real DOM" and apply them. This is based on the fact that its virtual DOM is much faster to manipulate than the real one.